# list with image, the image is not displayed

Tags: css

CSS

```
li.advantageItem {
    list-style-image: url('images/check.png');
    list-style-position: outside;
    color: #000000;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="advantageItem">
    <li class="advantageItem">.dfb</li>
    <li class="advantageItem">sdvfdb</li>
</ul>
```

Why isn't the advantageItem class applied to the list item?

Comment: Is images/check.png in that location relative to your css file?

Comment: As a quick debug for this sort of problem, you should change `color: #000000` to `color: red`. If the text is then red, you know that the problem is only with the image.

Comment: Can you attach screen shots of what the result is producing, and what it's supposed to look like? To me it looks like the CSS styling should be applied to the `<li>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a heirarchy around it that may prevent it getting the CSS applied correctly. For instance, sometimes stuff inside a table has to have additional tags to say apply it in the table or the table will 'deflect' application of the CSS. For example your class might have to be

Table li.advantageItem {

}

Check out your CSS application in IE's developer tools and it may give you an idea of what's happening. Open the page in IE, and go to Tools -> Developer tools (or press F12) then you can browse down your HTML and then see what CSS is being applied to it, and it's inheritance path (including stuff that was overridden).